# pearsons coefficient between rows R

Tags: r

Any help with the following problem would be much appreciated;

I am trying to use R to find the pearsons coefficient between 1 particular row of data with every other row in a dataset (separately), in order to determine which rows have a significant correlation with the row of interest.
The dataframe consists of 20 columns and 50,000 rows, the data itself consists of numerical values. 
Could the cor.test, or other appropriate function, be applied in such a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, I suggest reformatting your input object as a matrix rather than a data.frame.

You can use [`apply()`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/apply.html) to iterate over all rows of the matrix and run [`cor()`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/stats/html/cor.html) between the current row and the row of interest. This will produce a vector of correlations.

In the below code, I generate a random matrix `m` with 20 columns and 50,000 rows, and store the row of interest in `ri`. Then we can call `apply()` with row margin (that is, `MARGIN=1L`) to call `cor()` on each row against the row of interest `m[ri,]`.

You can choose to include or exclude the row of interest for the iteration. In my code sample below I include it, which results in an element guaranteed to have value 1 at index `ri` in the result vector `res`. A nice side effect of this choice is that the result vector will have length 50,000, the same as the number of rows in the input matrix, and thus the indexes will align. If you choose to exclude it, which can be done by passing `m[-ri,]` to the `apply()` call instead of just `m`, the result vector will have length 49,999, and its elements will no longer align with the rows of the input matrix.

```
NR <- 50e3L; NC <- 20L; m <- matrix(runif(NR*NC),NR);
ri <- 2L; res <- apply(m,1L,cor,m[ri,]);
str(res);
##  num [1:50000] -0.074 1 0.201 -0.0467 0.2097 ...
summary(res);
##      Min.   1st Qu.    Median      Mean   3rd Qu.      Max.
## -0.806700 -0.158500  0.001143  0.001114  0.160800  1.000000
```

You can replace `cor()` with [`cor.test()`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/stats/html/cor.test.html) to get the additional information provided by the latter, but at the expense of slightly longer run-time, and a more complex result object (a list instead of an atomic vector).

Comment: thank you very much this works. Could you possibly suggest how I could output the results into an excel sheet? I have tried using things like pvalues <- res$p.value, res$"p.value" etc and keep getting NULL messages.

Comment: If you're asking how to extract the P values from the list of `cor.test()` results, you can use `pvalues <- sapply(res,'[[','p.value')`. If you're asking how to export data from R to Excel, then I would recommend a [Google search](https://www.google.ca/search?q=export+r+to+excel). If none of the Google results work for your use-case, I would suggest asking a new question on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative solution would be to first transpose your `data.frame`, and then you could use a correlogram to visualize the correlations.

```
# transpose data
  df2 <- data.frame(t(df))


# Example of a correlogram using the `mtcars` dataset:
  library(corrgram)

  corrgram(mtcars, order=NULL, lower.panel=panel.shade,
           upper.panel=NULL, text.panel=panel.txt,
           main="your correlogram")
```

[image]